# How to pass a value to a popup window on open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I'm using a window from Telerik MVC extention, this window will pop up on event and will display a value that I'm passing to the window. So, I need to pass a value to that pop up window when it opens:

This is the pop up window

```
 Html.Telerik().Window()
           .Name("popUpWin")
           .Title("Submit")
           .Content(() => {%>
           <% using (Html.BeginForm("archExp", "Explorer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Submit" }))
              {%> 
            <p> Please specify Directory name</p>
             <label for="name">Name: </label>
                  <%=  Html.TextBox("name") %>



             <label for="name">Parent: </label>       
                 <%=  Html.TextBox("parent",  value ,new { @readonly = true })%>


                     <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="t-button">Submit !</button>
                        </div>
             <% }})
                .Width(200)
                .Draggable(true)
                .Modal(true)
                .Visible(false)
                 .Render();
                 %>
```

And here's the call to open it:

```
   //Open the Window
             $('#popUpWin').data('tWindow').open(**value**);
```

The problem is when I try to use that "value" inside the content of the window, it gives me

**Error 4   The name 'value' does not exist in the current context**

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript/ Jquery may be the solution.

```
    var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");        
    $("#Window").find("#yourinputId").val('**value**');        
    window.open();
```